# ¿Como conectarse a la base de datos con postgresql usando php?

Tags: php, postgresql

```
$dbservername = "localhost";
$dbusername = "postgres";

$dbname = "asistencia";
$dbpassword = "123456";

$puerto = "5432";


$con=pg_connect("host=localhost, dbname=asistencia, user=postgres, $dbname, $dbpassword");
```

Me he conectado antes a una base de datos usando xampp y mysql, pero en esta ocasión esta resultando especialmente problemático, he tratado de abordar la conexión de varias maneras y no logro hacer la conexión, con la conexión de arriba solo conseguí:

> Warning: `pg_connect()`: Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: missing
>   "=" after "asistencia," in connection info string in
>   `/var/www/html/libreta/conexion.php` on line 14

Por que esta faltando un `=` después de asistencia? No le veo el sentido, trate colocando el puerto después de asistencia, pero consigo el mismo error.

- El orden en que coloco los datos dentro de los paréntesis de `pg_connect()` tiene importancia?
- Veo que ahora se necesita un puerto para realizar la conexión, como me aseguro de que datos exactamente necesito y cuales son los de la maquina donde estoy trabajando?

Muchas dudas, sigo investigando, pero simplemente no lo logro hacer funcionar. Estoy usando **pgAdmin III**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu codigo deberia estar un poco mas limpio y si declaras las variables arriba no las estas usando abajo, podrias hacer algo como esto:

```
$dbservername = "localhost";
$dbusername = "postgres";
$dbname = "asistencia";
$dbpassword = "123456";
$puerto = "5432";
$con=pg_connect("host=$dbservername port=$puerto dbname=$dbname user=$dbusername password=$dbpassword");
```

Comment: Capo, efectivamente funcionó

Comment: Excelente, que bueno que se te pudo ayudar.

Answer (score 2):

```
$host="192.168.0.1";
$port="5432";
$user="postgres";
$pass="clave";
$dbname="db";

$connect = pg_connect("host=$host port=$port dbname=$dbname user=$user password=$pass") or die('No se ha podido conectar: ' . pg_last_error());
```

Creo que te hace falta el puerto pasarlo en la función

Answer (score 2):

Te comento que otra forma de conectarse es mediante el driver `PDO`; del modo siguiente

```
<?php 
$host="192.168.0.1";
$port="5432";
$user="postgres";
$pass="clave";
$dbname="db";

$dbh = new PDO("pgsql:dbname=$dbname;host=$host;port=$port", $user, $dbpass); 
?>
```

Donde como puedes notar al inicio le indicamos hacia que gestor debe apuntar cuando escribimos `pgsql`

Del mismo modo podemos pasarle el puerto de conexión

Aquí tienes mas referencias de parte de la documentación oficial de PHP

http://php.net/manual/es/ref.pdo-pgsql.connection.php